# Load toggle div on page open / refresh, while also passing variables from source page

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've been trying to figure this out for the past day, searched far and wide, gave up and am posting here - 1st post btw.

In short, I need to load a page with an open *div id="overview"*, and on click event, close it, and open *div id="cases"*.

And normally I'd use a simple div replace like this simply loading content in the *div id="replacer"*, easy peasy, BUT...

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#cases").click(function(){
         $("#replacer").html('blah1');
            });
    $("#overview").click(function(){
         $("#replacer").html('blah2');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

there's another issue,  where I need to have the *div id="cases"* be active instead when a user follows a specific link from another page. To do this I've hacked together the monstrosity below, and have the //SOURCE OPENER script passing the variable from the source page to load cases instead.

BUT, in the below code I can't figure out how to display the content in *div id="overview"* whenever the page is refreshed.

So if anyone could either help me pass a variable to open one of the above divs or look at what I have below, and advise I'd seriously be eternally grateful! Please help!!!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style>
 #contenido > div {display:none;}
</style>

<script>
var divState = {};
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;

    //close others
    for (var div in divState){
        if (divState[div] && div != id){
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
            divState[div] = false;
        }
    }

    divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'block' : 'block');
}
}

// SOURCE OPENER 1//
$(document).ready(function() {
// parse the query params
var url_params = (window.location.search.substr(1)
  .split('&')
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
      curr = curr.split('='); 
      if( curr.length > 1 ) { prev[curr.shift()]=curr.join('='); }
      return prev; 
  }, {}));

if( url_params.panel_open ) {
    // if "panel_open" was passed in the URL, then open the panel
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    divState['cases'] = true;
}

})

// SOURCE OPENER 2 //
$(document).ready(function() {
// parse the query params
var url_params2 = (window.location.search.substr(1)
  .split('&')
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
      curr = curr.split('='); 
      if( curr.length > 1 ) { prev[curr.shift()]=curr.join('='); }
      return prev; 
  }, {}));

if( url_params2.feature_open ) {
    // if "feature_open" was passed in the URL, then open the panel
    $(".default").toggle("fast");
    divState['overview'] = true;
}

})
;

</script>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('overview');">Overview</a>
<a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="showhide('cases');">Case</a>

<div id="contenido">
<div class="default" id="overview">Overview Stuff</div>
<div class="panel" id="cases">Case Stuff</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to change your css to:
`#contenido > div:not(#overview) {display:none;}`

Comment: Except then it doesn't toggle the overview div, when cases is clicked.